# Check for Data in a set of Textboxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am working on creating a project which allows the user to input user data including an address.  The data from the address is taken in multiple textbox fields for Street, City, State, Zip Code, and any additional information (like Unit # etc).

Now I am trying to set up some error checking and some error tooltips to provide the user with information when they are trying to submit the form data.  I need to set it up so that every field (except for information, that is optional) has data in it.  **EDIT:** I can't believe I forgot to mention this.  On the form, inputting address data is optional.  However I am trying to set it up so that if any field has data, it tells the user they need to have data in all the fields.

Right now I had a huge if statement set up to check for input:

```
If (Not street.Text.Equals("") And (city.Text.Equals("") Or state.Text.Equals("") Or code.Text.Equals(""))) Or
   (Not city.Text.Equals("") And (street.Text.Equals("") Or state.Text.Equals("") Or code.Text.Equals(""))) Or
   (Not state.Text.Equals("") And (street.Text.Equals("") Or city.Text.Equals("") Or code.Text.Equals(""))) Or
   (Not code.Text.Equals("") And (street.Text.Equals("") Or city.Text.Equals("") Or state.Text.Equals(""))) Or
   (Not info.Text.Equals("") And (street.Text.Equals("") Or city.Text.Equals("") Or state.Text.Equals("") Or code.Text.Equals(""))) Then
```

My question is simple.  Is there an easier way to do this than the above If statement?  Personally the If statement just looks super messy for me and I am trying to figure out if there is a different way to go about this.  The code works for what I need it to do, just wondering if there are different angles to approach this problem from.

Comment: Win forms has validator controls for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user compiles any of address fields, simply check if one of your mandatory field is empty.

```
If (Not street.Text.Equals("") Or Not city.Text.Equals("") Or Not state.Text.Equals("") Or Not code.Text.Equals("") Or Not info.Text.Equals("")) Then
    If (street.Text.Equals("") Or city.Text.Equals("") Or state.Text.Equals("") Or code.Text.Equals("")) Then
        Msgbox("If you want to provide an address please compile street, city, state and ZIP code.")
    End If
End If
```

Please consider using [`OrElse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/orelse-operator) instead of `Or`.

Also consider using [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `Equals`.

Comment: The issue with this, (which I just realized I omitted from the OP by mistake) is that entering an address is optional.  So the fields are allowed to be empty, but if you go to put in data, all the fields need data.

Comment: This doesn't work with spaces... `StringIsNullOrEmpty` would be better. A user can enter a space into any of these fields and bypass the check...

Comment: This is a great advice. I've never used `Equals` so I didn't think about this problem. But `StringIsNullOrEmpty` doesn't work either because `Empty` is a zero-length string, better use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.